# How do I use VBA to clear table and make it one row instead

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables

I have a table in Excel. It is 2 columns right now with about 50 rows. I want to clear the contents in VBA (I have a macro set up that runs smoothly and populates the table). I want it to be one ROW instead of 2 columns and 50 rows. What code lines do I need for this - I am new to VBA.

Thank you :)

I tried

```
Dim sTableName As String
Dim sSheetName As String
sSheetName = "VBAMacro"
sTableName = "ProductSale_Table"
Sheets(sSheetName).ListObjects(sTableName).Delete
```

but this simply removes content. I need to figure out how to clear it AND make it one row.

Comment: "Make it one row" does that mean you want to concatinate an entire table?  What is the goal... maybe example images may help?

Comment: If you want to delete the data, instead of `Sheets(sSheetName).ListObjects(sTableName).Delete`, you could use `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sSheetName).ListObjects(sTableName): If Not .DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then .DataBodyRange.Delete: End With`. The colons denote new lines.

Answer (score 0):

You should always set-up all `Worksheet` objects and `ListObject`(Table).

Try the modified code below:

```
Dim Tbl As ListObject
Dim sTableName As String
Dim sSheetName As String


sSheetName = "VBAMacro"
sTableName = "ProductSale_Table"

' Set the List-Object
Set Tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sSheetName).ListObjects(sTableName)
With Tbl
    .DataBodyRange.ClearContents ' clear contects from Table
        
    .Resize .Range.Resize(1, .Range.Columns.Count) ' resize range (rows and columns) of Table
End With
```

Comment: In my pre-existing code, where do I add this chunk? Right before "End Sub" at the very end?

Comment: @webpie take my code and replace it with the part you shared

Comment: You need 2 instead of 1 because 1 is not possible (`.Range` includes `.HeaderRowRange`). `ClearContents` is a good choice because OP would probably like to keep the formatting.